# Customer user fields will not save in WordPress 3.4

Tags: wordpress

I had been using a variety of custom user fields in WordPress (fields that show up on a user's profile). With the update to 3.4, those fields no longer save to the database.

Here's the code I've been using in my functions.php file. Does anyone know what needs to change for these to work in 3.4?

```
// Create Custom User Fields
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'appUserAnswers' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'appUserAnswers' );
function appUserAnswers( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Your Answers</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="question-1">Question 1</label></th>
            <td>
                <textarea type="text" name="question-1" id="question-1" class="regular-text" rows="5" cols="30"><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'question-1', $user->ID ) ); ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

// Save Custom User Fields
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'appSaveUserAnswers' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'appSaveUserAnswers' );
function appSaveUserAnswers( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    // Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'question-1' to the field ID.
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'matrix-diagnosis', $_POST['question-1'] );
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check what's in the $_POST with a `vardump`.

Comment: Thanks @janw... I'll start there.

Comment: BTW what you are doing  isn't save diretly saving a $_POST value

Comment: I neglected to include in this question the code I place directly on the front-end page where users submit there info. That does save directly from a $_POST value.

Comment: So users can put abuse this for SQL injection.....

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that? And how is this less safe than a user being able to update their bio or any other information in a Wordpress profile?

Comment: The build in WP fields have validation inside them also look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Input_Validation. & this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development#answer-46760 THIS IS BASIC SECURITY YOU SHOULD KNOW THIS.

Comment: Thanks @janw. I'm not a programmer - I'm a UI/UX guy and have been modifying Wordpress as a quick and ugly way to get an app concept up and running. Certainly not an ideal solution, but fills the short-term need. You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a simple fix. After some digging, I discovered that update_usermeta had been deprecated, but still worked in older versions of Wordpress. In this version, they pulled support altogether.

Replacing all instances of update_usermeta with update_user_meta solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Theme Check is a great plug-in for this.  Saved me a ton of time finding depreciated items when I upgraded to 3.3 upgrade and now 3.4. Here's the link  [WordPress Theme Check Plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/)